# Why was this particular flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I flagged an answer on the below question (the answer is now deleted by a moderator).

*[Display delete button in gridview in gridview base on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436040/display-delete-button-in-gridview-in-gridview-base-on-condition/30436580)*

Because the answer was blindly copied from another answer. Later the original answer was modified a bit.

My flag was declined with a comment:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

Was it because review was not done properly on the version of original answer when this copied answer was posted?

Is it wrong to raise such flags?

Comment: I also flagged it as not an answer but got declined with reason `declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`. Seriously I also don't know why it happened.

Comment: I've met similar issue, but answers were rather downvoted with comments about bad practice of copy/paste included rather than removed. Don't understand this system,,,

Comment: When flagging these it's best to use a custom flag with a message as rock-solid as possible. *"This is copy and pasted from this answer here: [link to answer](http://example.com) and specifically this revision: [link to specific revision](http://example.com) Here is a side-by-side comparison I made showing they are the same: [i.stack.imgur.com/blah/12345.png](http://example.com)"*

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I declined the flag at the time because the code in the answer differed from the original answer. I had missed that the original answer had since been edited.

Another flagger pointed out my mistake and I then deleted the copied answer.

Your flag was correct, I should have marked it as helpful at the time. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Is there any way revert it to correct flag as it shows declined in my profile?

Comment: No problems. Main purpose to create this post was to clarify if such flags should not be raised. It seems it is good to keep raising such flags.

Comment: @RahulNikate a few declined flags are not a problem. It's the way it goes. You have 187 helpful, so don't worry about it. Do exactly the same thing next time.

Comment: @BillWoodger That's cool.

Comment: @RahulNikate: there is not, sorry.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's ok. Thank you

Comment: Dammit Martijn.

Comment: @BoltClock: Dammit, Bolt found out I done a booger.